# Why do characters keep talking after dying, and how do I fix it?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Ever since I killed a certain character, people have been talking after dying. Context:

> So... I walked into the Emperor's room aboard the Katariah, expecting a full-on fight with the guards, some agents, and the man himself. Instead I found the Emperor telling me calmly to kill him. He was, in my opinion, quite rude about it indeed – kept going on about how he didn't have all day and whatnot, didn't notice that I was busy looting his chests. In any case, I wanted it to look better than "walk up to him and stab him in the face," so I drank my invisibility potion, walked up behind him, and backstabbed him. I got my epic animation, but... to my surprise, as I was about to leave the room, I see in the subtitles, "Go on, I'm not going to fight you." This remained even as I jumped up and down on his dead body, dragged it across the floor, lit it on fire, etc.

The body only stopped talking when I left the room, so it wasn't exactly a persistent problem, but I have had the same issue ever since; people I brutally murder like to talk back to me after they're dead. If anyone else has had this issue, how can I fix it?

Comment: Sounds like hemad

Comment: Perhaps, much like the beating of the tell-tale heart, what you're really hearing is the voice of your guilty conscience, you murderer!

Comment: Hey, I have _eaten_ human hearts, and they definitely did not beat after being dead.

Comment: Did you actually finish them off or was it just an arrow to the knee?

Comment: @AdamEberbach Yes, I did.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I was having this issue before enabling subtitles, but after enabling subtitles, I am frequently seeing others doing the same too. Try disabling subtitles, that might solve the problem.

Comment: Well, the problem is only in the subtitles anyway, so that's not exactly a solution.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug. Bethesda may patch it in the future, although I've seen it (in the PC version) too, and there doesn't appear to be any way to fix it except on Bethesda's end.

Answer (score 0):

Where is this quest? But anyway, are you using console commands? Sometimes when you use commands it does that, also when you talk to them, disengage, and kill them while they are still talking.

Comment: Xbox 360, so no commands. This quest is aboard the Katariah, which only exists when one gets pretty far through a certain assassin-y questline. In addition, the NPC killed had no actual conversation options, just one quote.